# Storing and displaying counted values - Activity Diagram UML

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

There's simply put rounded rectangles to depict actions and rectangles to depict a class diagram which performs an action.

Now there's this ticket counter that displays and logs the total minutes on your parking ticket (structure is predetermined) when you buy one. Then when emptying the ticket machine it prints the total. Does the counting or anything need to be placed in a rectangle or is it okay to put count total minutes in a rounded rectangle? For example: to save each ticket to the 'total' I have an action diagram saying "store counted minutes in total", before I say "delete minutes" and go back to the start of my diagram (next customer).

So basically what I don't understand is: firstly, counting and storing values can this just be done in a rounded rectangle? and secondly, if the the ticket needs to read "you reserved X minutes on parking number Y". I can't just say print minutes and print parking number right? How do I go about this?

[image]

Comment: `rectangles to depict a class diagram` : that has no sense and does not follow the UML standard. `a class diagram which performs an action` : that has no sense. Out of that if this is your question you are free to decide the level of detail you want to show in an activity, you can use fine or coarse grain. Your question is not enough precise to say more, and you do not show your diagram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should stop talking about rounded and straight rectangles. Use Action and Class appropriately. Your diagram shows actions of an activity which is part of some use case (scenario). Now, an activity diagram should explain some activity (or UC scenario) by actions in a certain control flow. That's mainly a business perspective and you use that as basis to talk with the actor to ensure his requirements are understood correctly.

In a later design phase you use that diagram in order to sketch a class model. You could adorn that AD with designed classes to depict how they are related to the flow control. However, it's not very common to do that. Usually you leave the ADs as they are and start the class design in parallel. What you should do is to create collaborations to link classes and use cases. For a fine grained design you create actions which are call behaviors (that is class operations perform something needed in the course of the activities actions). Alternatively/aditionally you use sequence diagrams to show class collaborations.

Re. your question in the title: you would not show a counter in an AD since that to much programming detail. However, you could show objects like `:Ticket` and use flow controls with these.

P.S. As a side note: you need a Merge for the upgoing control flow loops. Else you will have a lock at `Select next...` since it expects two tokens and will get only one. Bit of nitpicking since any human could understand what is meant. But from a pure UML view it would be wrong (resp. an automate would not run with that input).

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer definitely helped me a bunch.The requirements for this exercise were to make an activity diagram, specifically. So I won't create classes (yet).
Also, instead of saying in an activity "display minutes + parking space". Could I alternatively write "Display message your parking time is :minutes minutes in :space parking space". Or is this again too much programming detail for an AD. 

What bugs me is that the requirements of this exercise can only be fully addressed using class models, but it requires an AD.

Comment: You should avoid programming details. At best use an object flow with `Ticket`. And yes, UML lectures often suck since they are either wrong (when it comes to use cases) or constructed in impractical ways. See also my P.S. above

Comment: Do you mean `Merge` instead of  `Join` in the PS? I thought `Join` was only needed after a `Fork`